# Two different sized hard-coded Arrays into One 2-Dimensional Vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am using 2 ARRAYS OF DIFFERENT SIZES in One 2-Dimensional Vector, and my output is not correct. The arrays are size 4 and size 13.
I want COLUMN 0 to have: 55, 66, 77, 88.
I want COLUMNs 1-12 to have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,11 in EACH ROW.
It would seem that the 2nd loop for the size 13 array would need to loop 4 times in order to fill 4 rows, however, I'm not sure how to do that.
Here is what I have so far in code and output:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int typeArray[4] = {55,66,77,88}; 
 int valArray[13] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,11}; 

// 4 = LENGTH or NUMBER of ROWS; 13 = WIDTH or NUMBER of COLUMNS; 
//  0 = VALUE all cells are initialized to 
 vector< vector <int> > myVector(4, vector<int> (14,0)); 

  for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)  
    { 
        myVector[i][0] = typeArray[i]; 
    for (int j = 0; j < myVector[i].size(); j++)  
      { 
         myVector[1][j] = valArray[j]; 
      } 
   } 
   // print vector to screen with 4 ROWS, 1 COLUMNS 
    for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size();  i++) 
      {          
        for (int j = 0; j < myVector[i].size(); j++) 
         {  
          cout << myVector[i][j] << ' '; 
          }          
          cout << '\n'; 
      }
```

---

OUTPUT----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
55 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0----first row-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10 10 11----second row-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
77 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0-------third row----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
88 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0-------fourth row

---

```
int typeArray[4] = {55,66,77,88}; 
 int valArray[14] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,11}; 

// 4 = LENGTH or NUMBER of ROWS; 13 = WIDTH or NUMBER of COLUMNS; 
//  0 = VALUE all cells are initialized to 
 vector< vector <int> > myVector(4, vector<int> (14,0)); 

  for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)  
    { 
        myVector[i][0] = typeArray[i]; 

    for (int j = 0; j < myVector[i].size(); j++)  
      { 
         myVector[1][j + 1] = valArray[j]; 
      } 
   } 
   // print vector to screen with 4 ROWS, 14 COLUMNS 
    for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size();  i++) 
      {          
        for (int j = 0; j <= myVector[i].size(); j++) 
         {  
          cout << myVector[i][j] << ' '; 
          }          
          cout << '\n'; 
      }
```

---

OUTPUT----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
55 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10 10 11----first row-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
66 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10 10 11----second row--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
77 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10 10 11----third row----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
88 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10 10 11----fourth row

---

### This is the revised code per Kerrek's update, it works perfectly:

```
 int typeArray[4] = {55,66,77,88}; 
 int valArray[13] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,11}; 

// 4 = LENGTH or NUMBER of ROWS; 13 = WIDTH or NUMBER of COLUMNS; 
//  0 = VALUE all cells are initialized to 
 vector< vector <int> > myVector(4, vector<int> (14,0)); 

 for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) 
    {
       myVector[i][0] = typeArray[i];

   for (int j = 1; j < myVector[i].size(); j++) 
     {
         myVector[i][j] = valArray[j - 1];
     }

   } 

  // print vector to screen with 4 ROWS, 14 COLUMNS
  for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
      {         
        for (int j = 0; j < myVector[i].size(); j++)
         { 
          cout << myVector[i][j] << ' ';
          }         
          cout << '\n';
      }
```

---

OUTPUT IS THE SAME AS THE 2ND BLOCK OF CODE, YES!

Comment: `myVector[1][j] = valArray[j];` Why is this "1" and not "i"?

Comment: My point was that by putting 1 in that location, his loop wasn't doing something that it would otherwise do and that he claimed to not know how to do. He may have had a reason for this that no longer applies.

Comment: Good job rewriting the code without actually mentioning what was wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
vector< vector <int> > myVector(4, vector<int> (14, 0));   // one longer!

for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)  
{ 
    myVector[i][0] = typeArray[i]; 
    for (int j = 1; j < myVector[i].size(); j++)  
    { 
         myVector[i][j] = valArray[j - 1]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast correction. I still have a couple more questions.  If I don't change the 2nd array size to be 14, the program stalls:    int typeArray[4] = {55,66,77,88};
                   int valArray[14] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,11};

Comment: I am posting the revised code above, would you please advise the correct way to handle this, thanks!

Comment: @codechick: Leave the array size at 13. I just made the *vector* one longer, because you seem to want to prepend `typeArray` as the first column.

Comment: If I do that the program hoses up...??

Comment: @codechick: oh, I'm very sorry, I made a very stupid mistake. Fixed!

Comment: Kerrek, thanks for the quick responses.  I'm actually glad to see everything (doesn't work, works) as that's how I learn.  The revised code is posted above.  And in the interest of ShiggityShiggityShwa's comment and my own learning, would you please clarify how the tweaks you made to the code work?  Thanks again.